# Is it okay to purposely post a question and answer for the sole purpose of helping someone else?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

This is not rocket science, but I don't want to have to guide people step-by-step on doing things through chat boxes.

Is it alright if I create a question (if it hasn't been asked yet), and briefly after answer it so that I can simply link them to the question page for them to look at it, for example (not that some of them belongs on this site):

> How do I send a trade offer on Steam?
>   How do I export a Word Document into a PDF?
>   How do I teleport a player in Minecraft?*

(Of course, the restrictions would be that I cannot mark an answer, unless someone else did it 24 hours after I post the answer).

But my point is: **Should I not do it at all, mark at as the community wiki or simply just leave everything as is?**

*Okay, a question like this shouldn't be asked at all, due to the fact it can be Googled and the answer can be conveyed through a single line of chat, but that's not the point.

Comment: [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). When you do, you are obviously helping someone else. Keep in mind, though, that the question has to remain on topic.

Comment: Yeah, but what's the conventions for it? Should I mark it as a community wiki or leave it as-is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes, that's what this site is for.

As [Nolornar pointed out](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10157/is-it-okay-to-purposely-post-a-question-and-answer-for-the-sole-purpose-of-helpi#comment29258_10157), [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). And making a public resource to help other people is 100% what that's for.

As to marking it as a Community Wiki, you can do that if you want, but [I'd suggest only using it when appropriate](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/). It's fine to leave your Q and A as a non-community wiki and let the users of the site determine whether it's useful or not (that's largely what up/downvotes are for).

That said, there is still the requirement that your Q&A be [on-topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and if it isn't, we can't really help you.